# How to do remote validation for group in Jquery

Tags: jquery-validate

I had used Jquery groups for combine multiple fields.Now i would like to do remote validation for all the three as a group.But it's not working.Can we use the remote..Remote not worked for me.Help would be appreciate.

Comment: Please add some of the code that is not working.

Comment: hi andrew,thanx for the reply.I had not understand.Can you elaborate.